# How can I pass a list of properties to a method using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

Let's say I have a method, which prints the names and values of some properties of an object:

```
public void PrintProperties(object o, params string[] propertyNames)
{
    foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
    {
        // get the property info,
        // then get the property's value,
        // print property-name and -value
    }
}
// method can be used like this
PrintProperties(user, "FirstName", "LastName", "Email");
```

Now instead of having to pass a list of strings to the method, **I'd like to change that method** so that the properties can be specified using lambda expressions (not sure if that's the correct term).

E.g. I'd like to be able to call my method (somehow) like this:

```
PrintProperties(user, u->u.FirstName, u->u.LastName, u->u.Email);
```

The goal is, to give the user of the method intellisense support, to prevent typing errors.
(Similar to the ASP.NET MVC helper methods, like `TextBoxFor(u=>u.Name)`).

How do I have to define my method, and how can I then get the `PropertyInfo`s inside the method?

Answer (score 8):

Use a declaration like this:

```
void PrintProperties<T>(T obj,
                        params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] propertySelectors)
{
   ...
}
```

Callable like:

```
PrintProperties(user, u => u.FirstName, u => u.LastName, u => u.Email);
```

As for getting property-names out from each lambda, see [Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671968/412770). Do note that you have may have to go a little bit deeper than what is provided in that answer in case the property is a value-type like `int` (in this case, the compiler will generate a unary `Convert` expression over the member-access that you want, in order to box the struct).

Comment: How do I then get the values of the object using the property selectors?

Answer (score 1):

Reflection allows you to access fields, properties, events, etc.

```
public void PrintProperties(object o, params string[] propertyNames)
{
    foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
    {
        // Dont have VS now, but it's something like that
        Console.WriteLine(o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(o, null));
    }
}
```

I don't have VS now, so it might not even compile, but along these names you can get along with auto-completion...

Comment: That's what I have now. Please read the second part of the question :-)

Comment: If you pass the the properties themselves, though... you can't know which property you just got from a lambda expression, so you won't be able to print it's name. I assumed you wanted something like `"A: 3, B: 5, Name: Hi"`

Comment: That's correct: I need to get the properties' names and values

Comment: So that's the way to do it. Why no reflection?